# Zeppelin does not see dependencies from custom repository

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I want to add company artifactory to Zeppelin spark interpreter and try to use this [document](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/manual/dependencymanagement.html).

So, the URL of our artifactory looks like

`http://artifactory.thecompany.com:8081/artifactory/`

The access is not restricted to specific user and artifacts are downloadable both from my machine and from machine where Zepplin is running (I tried this with curl).

I've copied the artifact ID from by `build.gradle`, so I am pretty sure it is correct. However when I try to add the artifact that should be found in my company's artifactory I get error

> Error setting properties for interpreter 'spark.spark': Could not find
>   artifact
>   com.feedvisor.dataplatform:data-platform-schema-scala:jar:3.0.19-SNAPSHOT
>   in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

This error message sounds like Zeppelin did not try to look for my dependency in custom repository.

I tried to play with artifactory URL using:

- http://artifactory.thecompany.com:8081/artifactory/
- http://artifactory.thecompany.com:8081/

as well as with "snapshot" property of "Add New Repository" form (using `true` and `false`) but nothing helped. The error message does not disappear and classes from the referenced artifact are not found.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For Zeppelin to use your company's repo by default you can set `ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DEP_MVNREPO` in your `${Z_HOME}/conf/zeppelin-env.sh`:

```sh
export ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DEP_MVNREPO=http://artifactory.thecompany.com:8081/artifactory/
```

Alternatively, you can use [Dynamic Dependency Loading](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/spark.html#3-dynamic-dependency-loading-via-sparkdep-interpreter) feature of the notebook:

```
%dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Artifactory").url("http://artifactory.thecompany.com:8081/artifactory/").snapshot()
z.load("com.feedvisor.dataplatform:data-platform-schema-scala:3.0.19-SNAPSHOT")
```

Comment: Are there any other configuration options you needed to set to get this to work? It seems like part of the problem is the resolver is adding ":jar:" to the coordinates.

Comment: @dpk Is that a problem? The Maven coordinate system, IIRC is `groupId:artifactId:version:packaging` and the latter is `jar`.